# How to fetch new products from all category in magento 1.7.0?

Tags: php

I want to show latest added products from all or some specific categories on home page.
I'm trying in this way, I have created a block and the block code is here :

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()- >toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir());

    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'))
    {
        $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'));
    }


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

    $this->_productCollection = $products;

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

But it only showing me last category's products. Suppose I have Imported 100 products for a **xyz** category then it  showing me products from **xyz** category only. But I don't want this. I want to show new products from all or some specific category. Any help will be great appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              )
            ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1)
        ;

        return $collection;
    }
```

may be this is help ful for you.